# Move row to another sheet's first row base on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My code working good to move row to another sheet base on Column9's value.
But it moving the row to the last row of target sheet.
Is there anyway to move the row and insert to the second row of the target sheet ?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "TODO" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == "Hoàn thành") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DONE");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: Do you want to move a row to another sheet's last row? Could you please provide more information and a public copy of the sheets?

Answer (score 1):

```
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TestingTesting");  
      var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
// get the data from source location, in this case row 15 starting with column1, only one row and all columns. rowVal is an array with the values from your source.
      let rowVal = sheet.getRange(15, 1, 1, lastCol).getValues(); 
// this is the empty row you wanted to be in second line
      sheet.insertRows(2);  
// this is adding data you acquired from source into that new row
      sheet.getRange(2,1,1,lastCol).setValues(rowVal);
```

Comment: thank for your comment. where to put this code. can you please tell me where to insert your code?

i tried insert before and after if fucntion. both not working

Comment: This is a low quality answer, there is no explanation of what this code is trying to achieve. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. @HiểnHồ I recommend you to open a new post providing more information about your issue as some users asked in your original post. The more information you provide, the more chances you will get a helpful answer.

Comment: @Jescanellas I added explanation which you were not interested in doing. I am just a beginner and resent the minus one.

Comment: Good! Of course I wasn't interested, it's your answer, not mine. I added the documentation link which was more than enough, others just downvote without saying anything.